# Отправка сообщений каждый день в определонное время всем пользователям в сети discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Вот написаний мною код хочу сделать так чтоб бот реагировал не на команду а на время к примеру если время 10 утра бот исполняет команду !online_sendоднако если пытаюсь убрать декаротор @bot.command() и запустить эту команду через условия с помощю datetime аргумент ctx не работает свойственно и код не работает так как нужно. Помогите хоть кто-то.

```
import discord


from discord.ext import commands
from config import token, text


intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['!'], intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot online')



@bot.command()
async def online_send(ctx):
    mbrs = ctx.guild.members
    print(mbrs)
    online = list(filter(lambda x: x.status == discord.Status.online, mbrs))
    for member in online:
        await member.send(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через [таск](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html):

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.index = 0
        self.printer.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.printer.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
    async def printer(self):
        print(self.index)
        self.index += 1
```